# Google-Drive-related shell_ipc_client.cc errors from filedialog (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

Consider this Python script, the first lines of which are meant to ask for an input file:

```
import os
import csv

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

from setup import *
    
# Input the piece of music

input('Select a piece of music, in XML format.')
print()

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

piece_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
file_name = piece_path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

When running this (VS Code 1.63.2, on Win10), execution freezes after the text is displayed:

```
Select a piece of music, in XML format.
```

If at that point I press Enter in the terminal, I get:

```
[10284:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[10284:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[13220:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[9136:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[10284:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[9136:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[9176:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[9136:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[10284:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[9136:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[9176:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[9176:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[9176:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[9136:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
[9176:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:116:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_z8080_shell
```

These error messages aren't very helpful: this .py file is local on my PC, and I have no app open that uses Google Drive in any way. I have a firewall, but these errors happen even if I turn it off. The current directory has been changed to the location of the py file, prior to running.

SHould say that, upon running this code I did get a OpenFile window, which I accidentally closed, and which never appeared again, despite not having changed anything in the code!

Comment: What's this `setup` module you're using? Have you tried removing it from your code? The lack of the OpenFile window could be explained by remaining background processes that didn't exit properly. I don't know what system you have, but on Linux you can get the list of processes by running `ps aux`. You can then `grep` it for your program name. For example, `ps aux | grep test.py`. Again, I can't be sure that it's extra processes that are causing it, but try both checking the processes and removing `from setup import *`, and let me know how that goes.

Comment: The `setup.py` is a part of the repo at https://github.com/GermanRuizMarcos/AuToTen. Don't think it can be removed as it's needed for computations further on in the script. Having run the main script a few more times, I do sometimes get the openFile window opening up behind other windows, and after some delay - it's very random!

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know! And that OpenFile window randomness is very odd; usually `tkinter` is quite consistent. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what's going on there, as there are so many factors that could play a part in messing up the OpenFile window.

Comment: sadly I also can't quite reproduce it, but I managed to get through the various file inputs with a series of Enters in the terminal window, followed by more of those `shell_ipc_client` error messages, followed by minimising the VS Code window to see if ay openFile window popped up underneath (which it would). Strange..

Comment: Ah, yes. You _would_ have to press `Enter` in the terminal in order for it to work, since you use the `input()` function instead of `print()`. Is that intended behavior? Also, what's your operating system? Judging by the backslashes in the port paths, you're on a Windows. Maybe the window popped up underneath VSCode because you were pressing enter in the terminal, and the window was forced out of the way (?) You're right, this is all strange, but there must be a reason...

Comment: I think you probably nailed it, this sounds plausible. I didn't write the code, but I did assume Enter had to be pressed before posting this thread, but on those occasions I got no openFile window behind - or maybe it was there but I hadn't noticed. Am indeed on WIndows. What's interesting is that the script does go on despite the Google Drive errors.

Comment: The Google Drive errors don't look like actual Python tracebacks. Usually errors that stop the program start with `Traceback: (most recent call last)...`. Some Python modules that were originally coded in other languages may have error messages that don't stop execution. For example, [tag:gtk] has error messages that result from undefined tags in tooltip markup, but they just print something like `my-app:325284): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:07:29.446: Failed to set text '<markup><p...`, and program execution continues.

Comment: Did you solve this issue over time? Or did it 'fix itself' in time? I'm asking because I just ran into the same error and I can't explain it either.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me to with `fiedialog.askopenfilename()` when my google drive was not on. so my Google drive I: looked like I:?.

```
`2023-01-06T09:07:05.111ZE [12776:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:129:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_Y_shell `
```

After opening google drive app and trying `filedialog.askopenfilename()` again it worked without problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had the same error and just starting google drive app on my pc solved it. It is still unclear why this was happening, as my code is in no way using google drive.